# RegExp Validate First http

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need a regex for removing first http from my input box. how can i do this ?

For example if value of my input box is http://welcome.com  it remove http:// and convert it to welcome.com

Comment: You want so much. Could you phrase a proper question please?

Comment: Hiya guys! `:)` I reckon english is not OPs first language but we should be considerate and try to understand what s/he wants, **OP you should sit back and think before asking questions SO is awesomeness :) so give quality question please** Anyhoo do you mean this: http @babakfaghihian **Working Demo =>** http://jsfiddle.net/RgcRz/

Comment: @mizipzor: You can edit the question to try and help clarify it instead, specially if your only concern was a questionmark. That would have been more productive I think.

Comment: I think all he want's is to parse the string if it contains 'http://'  or not,,

Comment: @MohammadAdil I have provided a demo see above `:)` I reckon same

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: I tried but failed to figure out what the actual problem is. I have also learned that improving question of this level of quality is *usually* a practice in futility since they are closed by the time I submit the change.

Comment: @mizipzor: I would try edit and if something is not clear and I can't edit I ask. If I feel all that is missing is a questionmark I edit it and add it. If the question is closed in the meantime, so be it, at least I tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need regular expressions?
indexOf() can do the job:

```
function CheckLink()
{
    var token = "http://";
    var link = "www.example.com";

    if(link.indexOf(token)!=0)
        link = token + link;

    return link;
}
```

Comment: @babakfaghihian Please don't be offensive. The people here are trying to help you but they are not willing to carry out your orders.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know how to do this, because you should avoid adding `http` or `https` to  your links.

Use `<a href="//www.example.com">click me</a>` instead.

See: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^http/) )this.value='http://'+this.value"
```

Comment: I don't understand :) this is a valid example, you just add it to the input field of your choice like: <input type="text" value="www.example.com" id="txt_url" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^http/) )this.value='http://'+this.value" />​ And, on key up, if the value doesn't contain http at its start, it automatically adds it

Comment: i test it bro its ok but i want to check the frist 7 alphabet in this code in your code from first it have http:// i dont want this i want to chek 7 frist alphabet if it not http:// then it add http

Comment: :) hey, ok my code doesn't check the first seven..but the first 4..ok. Change the 'this.value.match(/^http/)' with 'this.value.match(/^http\:\/\//)' - now is seven. Or, possibly I don't understand what you'r asking

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="www.example.com" id="txt_url" />​
```

**JS**

```
var el=document.getElementById('txt_url');
el.onblur=function()
{
    var str=el.value;
    if(str=='') return;    
    if(str.indexOf('http://')==-1) 
    el.value='http://'+str;    
}
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/krKmU/3/)

Comment: You better use blur event, just write something like `www.example.com` in the text box and it'll change on blur.

Comment: its work only if i press tab i want to on keyup this function do job

Comment: But I think you should use blur instead of keyup.

Comment: Blur means that the event will fire after the user leaves the textbox so it'll check only once after you finished writing and leave the textbox.

Comment: Keyup is not perfect for this job.

Comment: keyup is better for me i know

Comment: It'll fire the event repeatedly.