# RegExp For Validate Link

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate 7 first alphabet of my input box my code is doesn't work.

```
<input type="text" value="www.example.com" id="txt_url"  
 onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^http\:\/\//) && (txt_url.lenght >= 7 )this.value='http://'+this.value" />
```

Comment: Ok, it seems the second step after this one: [regexp-validate-first-http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325961/regexp-validate-first-http), isn't it. Next time, before posting two question for the same problem, try to state the problem, slice it in subproblems, try to solve each of them, and eventually, post a single question describing what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

There are three reasons why that code doesn't work:

1. `lenght` should be `length`.
2. `txt_url.length` should be `this.value.length`.
3. You're missing a closing `)` at the end of the `if` condition.

Working version:

```
<input type="text" value="www.example.com" id="txt_url"  
 onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^http\:\/\//) && (this.value.length >= 7))this.value='http://'+this.value" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J5Uxt/

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake in the function which you have used.(txt_url.lenght).

It should be txt_url.length i believe. Also, if you want to validate a url, there are better regular expressions available on the net.

Answer (score 0):

- avoid inline (DOM zero) events and handle this sort of thing centrally
- you have a typo in `lenght`.
- are you quite sure you want to do this on key up, rather than, say, on blur, or form submit? It would surely be annoying for the user if you modified the field value every time he or she pressed a key

The below assumes blur, but you can change the event to whatever you want:

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#text_url').on('blur', function() {
        if (!/https?:\/\//.test($(this).val()))
            $(this).val('http://'+$(this).val());
    });
});
```

**Native JS:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#text_url').addEventListener('blur', function() {
        if (!/https?:\/\//.test(this.value))
            this.value = 'http://'+this.value;
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad - fixed. Missed a bracket :) Here's the jQuery version [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/cC4sH/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code corrected is

```
<input type="text" value="www.example.com" id="txt_url"
onkeyup="if(this.value.match(/^http\:\/\//)==null 
&& this.value.length>7)this.value='http://'+this.value;" />
```

But if you want to automatically put http:// prefix even for shorter domain names like ab.com
then you might use

```
<input type="text" value="www.example.com" id="txt_url"
onkeyup="if(this.value.match(/^h(t(t(p(\:(\/(\/)?)?)?)?)?)?/)==null)
this.value='http://'+this.value;" />
```